# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^N d_3(n) = N \log^2(N) + O(N \log N)$

Tags: number-theory

I'm working through the following problem:

Let $d_3(n)$ denote the number of ordered triples of integers whose product is $n$. Prove that $$ \sum_{n=1}^N d_3(n) = N \log^2(N) + O(N \log N).$$

The hint that is given is "Count the lattice points with positive coordinates on or under the surface defined by $xyz = N$." The hint makes me think the solution is quite intuitive, and doesn't involve any kind of manipulation with Dirichlet convolution and what not. That being said, I'm struggling in seeing it. Could someone lend me a hand?

Comment: Draw a cube $a+ [0,1]^3$ around each lattice point $a \in \Bbb{Z}^3$ and look at $A(N) = \bigcup_{ a \in \Bbb{Z}^3, |a_1a_2a_3| \le N} a+[0,1]^3$. The goal is to say $B(N-1) \subset A(N) \subset B(N+1)$ where $B(t) = \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3, |xyz| \le x\}$ and to conclude with $Vol(A(N)) =  Vol(B(N-1))+O(Vol(B(N+1)-Vol(N-1)) =8 N \log^2 N + O(N\log N)$.